# Print all the usernames of users as well as their home directories

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I'm trying to print all the usernames of users as well as their home directories. All I have found online is how to change the passwords etc. Could someone please guide me to figure this out?

`echo $HOME` only prints one, not all on the system.

Comment: See [How can I list all user names and/or home directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409407/264812).  The top (most upvoted) 
 answer is excellent, and contains all the information that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk way**

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291452/546660
awk -F":" '{print "User: "$1 "Home Dir: "$6}' /etc/passwd
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291452/546660

Answer (score 3):

Use getent(1) in order to output all entries regardless of whether they're stored in a networked database or merely in /etc/passwd.  Using getent() is important for environments which use a centrally managed user database.  Also, in general one should avoid relying on specific pathnames for system functionality.

Here's a sample of the information that getent returns:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Here's the command to run and some output (thanks Constantin for reminding me of awk's "-F" option).

```
$ getent passwd |awk -F: '{print $1 "\t" $6}'
root    /root
bin     /bin
```

Explanation:

- The awk option "-F:" changes the field separator character to a colon.
- $1 refers to the first field (the username)
- "\t" prints a <TAB> character.
- $6 refers to the sixth field (the home directory)

Make it as pretty as you like by editing the print command, changing it to awk's printf, etc.

--klode

Answer (score 1):

That info is stored in `/etc/passwd`.  So here's one way to read it with bash and echo (as you have tagged):

```bash
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do 
 echo "User $f1 stores files in $f6"
done < /etc/passwd
```

(from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there will be ton of suggestions, so there is mine.

Simple and short with *cut* but without fancy output formatting:

```
cut -d":" -f1,6 /etc/passwd
```